# Is there a Linux VLC version which supports the SRT (Secure Reliable Transport) protocol?

Tags: software-installation, video, vlc, binary, video-streaming

I use [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) to stream live video using the [SRT protocol](https://www.srtalliance.org/about-srt-technology/).

To receive the stream, the current Windows and MacOS versions of VLC can be used.

But the Linux versions were compiled without libsrt, and cannot receive SRT streams. I checked the version in the Ubuntu repository: `vlc/focal 3.0.9.2-1`, and also [the nightly PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu): `4.0.0~rc1~~git20210808+r89110+251~ubuntu20.04.1`.

I could of course try to compile it myself. But I suspect that, because of the huge number of codecs and containers that it supports, compiling it with all it's libraries would be quite cumbersome.

So, does anyone know where I could find a pre-compiled binary of VLC for Linux which has libsrt enabled?

Comment: That is a question for the VLC people not Ubuntu. https://www.videolan.org/support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can run some package analysis on https://packages.ubuntu.com and locally installed 20.04 LTS:

1. the *Secure Reliable Transport UDP streaming library* is provided by `srt` [source package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/srt)
2. the most interesting binary package which is produced from source `srt` package is [`libsrt1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libsrt1)
3. running reverse dependency check against `libsrt1` on 20.04 LTS gives the following output:

   > ```
   > $ apt-cache rdepends libsrt1
   > libsrt1
   > Reverse Depends:
   >  libsrt-dev
   >  vlc-plugin-base
   >  vlc-plugin-access-extra
   >  srt-tools
   >  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
   > ```

So you have to install two VLC related packages by

```
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-access-extra
```

and then retry accessing SRT stream.